# expected_conditions._find_element throws an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Tags: python, selenium

I have to wait some element appearances, and I use:

```
re_enter_email_field = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                expected_conditions._find_element(By.ID,"u_0_f"))
```

But each time I run a test, I get an error:

```
Error

  File "/home/akop/py_workspace/MacPaw_FB/pages/LoginPage.py", line 56, in submit_new_account_form
    expected_conditions._find_element(By.ID,"u_0_f"))
  File "/home/akop/py_workspace/t_sade_site/site_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 398, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

Comment: I thinks your element is not there

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using Python, but on Java I do that like this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, EXPLICIT_TIMEOUT)
            .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return driver.findElements(By.id("my_id")).isEmpty();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer was much easier: extra parenthes around `(By.ID,"u_0_f")` solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is mean of this code as I have very less knowledge of python But it is not correct I guess:

```
expected_conditions._find_element(By.ID,"u_0_f")
```

But expected_conditions should have condition to be followed like element_to_be_clickable, presence_of_element_located or visibility_of_element_located etc.

You should try like this

```
re_enter_email_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(By.ID,"u_0_f"))
```

or

```
re_enter_email_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(By.ID,"u_0_f"))
```

or

```
re_enter_email_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID,"u_0_f"))
```